# Ajuda na estilização do CSS que não estou conseguindo resolver!

Tags: html, css

Queria uma ajuda de vocês, estou fazendo este formulário de login, estou estilizando ele, mas daí quando fui tentar colocar o animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
Simplesmente o "btn-anim1" não está sendo reconhecido.
[image: como está mostrando acima, o comando "btn-anim1" não está sendo reconhecido]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
    <title>Aprendendo .dev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tela-de-login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="/css/mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a class="logo" href="/">teste 01</a>
            <div class="mobile-menu">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="/">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Modelos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Tops 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Sobre</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <h3>Registra-se</h3>
<!--FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO-->

<div class="login-box">
    <h4>login</h4>
    <form>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="" required="">
            <label>E-mail</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="password" name="" required>
            <label>SENHA</label>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            ENTRAR
        </a>
    </form>
</div> 

    <main>

    </main>
    <script src="/scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

    /* CUSTUMIZAÇÃO GERAL */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

  /* BACKGROUND DA PÁGINA(IMG) */

  body {
      
    background: url("/img/principal.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 90vh;
    }


a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;               
}

  body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #323232;        
  }
  
  body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #323232;
    border-radius: 6px;       
    border: 3px solid 
  }

/* PARTE DA NAV */

.logo {
font-size: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 4px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background: #23232e;
    height: 12vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-list li {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

/* PARTE DE CONTEÚDOS DA PÁGINA */

h3 {
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    background: url("/img/principal.jpg");
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 8vh;
}

/* PARTE DO FORMULARIO DE LOGIN */

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background: linear-gradient(#000000, #434343);
}

.login-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.login-box h3 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.login-box .user-box {
    position: relative;
}

.login-box .user-box input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.login-box .user-box label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.login-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
.login-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #ff0043;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.login-box form a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #ff0043;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.login-box a:hover {
    background: #ff0043;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0043,
                0 0 25px #ff0043,
                0 0 50px #ff0043,
                0 0 100px #ff0043;
}

.login-box a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.login-box a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #ff0043);
    animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes btn-anim1 {
    0% 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

tenho um código aqui referente a criação de um button, da uma olhada

```
<h2>Animated Button</h2>
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Hover </span></button>
```

Acredito que está faltando algo pra se codar no seu HTML

Answer (score 0):

Tudo bem?

Em relação ao seu seletor: .login-box a span:nth-child(1), já verificou se trecho está realmente selecionando o elemento span html.

Outra observação sobre o seu keyframe:

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
0%
}

Ele não faz nada com somente esse 0%, tenta adicionar alguma função para a sua animação, tipo (width entre outras...)